# Wowza live stream allow only video and stop audio stream

Tags: video-streaming, wowza

I am getting wowza live stream from ip-cam, stream is running perfectly but audio stream in not required in my case, can anyone tell me how to disable audio streaming and get only video streaming in wowza live application

Answer (score 2):

For `RTSP/RTP`:

> **How to turn on/off audio and video tracks**
>
> You can turn off audio or video tracks by adding the `rtspStreamAudioTrack` and `rtspStreamVideoTrack` custom properties.

In `<MediaCaster><Properties>`:

```
<Property>
    <Name>rtspStreamAudioTrack</Name>
    <Value>false</Value>
    <Type>Boolean</Type>
</Property>
```

It was right there in the [documentation](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?39-How-to-re-stream-video-from-an-IP-camera-(RTSP-RTP-re-streaming))